# Can I travel to UK with a german blue passport?

Tags: uk

I have a german blue passport, under Geneva Convention. Can I travel to the UK with someone that has a GERMAN Passport and is a british resident? Or with a sponsor from a family member in the UK with a UK passport?
https://www.gov.uk/check-uk-visa/y/stateless-or-refugee/tourism/yes/yes
Under this link it says yes, but i dont get what they mean?

Answer (score 1):

The link you've provided indicates that you have a valid Article 10 residence card.  This means that you live in Germany with an EU-citizen family member.  If that is correct, you are exempt from the visa requirement *if you travel with (or visit) the EU-citizen family member who sponsored you for the German article 10 card* ("The person you’re visiting or travelling with must be your sponsor").

If this is the case, then you can travel without a visa as outlined at [Entering the UK as the holder of an Article 10 residence card](https://www.gov.uk/government/publications/entering-the-uk-as-the-holder-of-an-article-10-residence-card/entering-the-uk-as-the-holder-of-an-article-10-residence-card).  If either of the following is true, however, you will need a visa:

- You do not have an article 10 residence card (that is, your card does not say "residence card of a family member of a union citizen" on it).
- You have an article 10 card, but the person through whom you got that card is not in the UK and will not be traveling with you to the UK.

If a person you're visiting or traveling with is your family member as defined in the free movement directive (principally a spouse or partner, a dependent parent, or a child who is either under 21 or dependent on you), and is an EU citizen *but not a UK citizen,* then you can travel with an [EEA family permit](https://www.gov.uk/family-permit/eligibility).  Otherwise, you'll need a [standard visitor visa](https://www.gov.uk/standard-visitor-visa) (or, depending on the purpose of your visit, some other type of visa).